# Operating Systems: Activation Frames vs. Process Control Blocks

Tags: operating-system, kernel

From my understanding, both activation frames and process control blocks are in the runtime stack, which is part of the kernel?

That doesn't seem right... Either the runtime stack is not part of the kernel, or activation frames don't belong in the runtime stack?

Comment: **Which** runtime stack do you mean, **kernel** (for kernel code) or **user** (for user-space program)? Stack for kernel code is located in the kernel, stack for user program is located in the user space. Process Control Block is located in the kernel stack (or at another adress accessible for the kernel only).

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I got the two confused. I thought there was only 1 runtime stack, but there are as many runtime stacks (for user programs) as processes.

Comment: @pastalover1234 no.  There are as many user stacks as there are user threads.

Comment: @MartinJames Thank you for pointing that out. Yes that makes sense, a program may have multiple threads. I will amend my statement.

Answer (score 0):

Each process has a runtime stack. N process = N runtime stacks (EDIT: assuming each process doesn't have multiple threads. A better statement is N threads = N runtime stacks).

The kernel stack is separate. The PCB table lives in the kernel stack.

Kernel stack != runtime stack. <s>There is also only 1 kernel stack, while there are many runtime stacks.</s>

Comment: `There is also only 1 kernel stack, while there are many runtime stacks.` - No. Unless OS uses "green" threads, there is 1:1 mapping from kernel threads to user ones.

Comment: That is a great exception. I will amend my statement. 
For reference, green threads are threads that are scheduled by a runtime library or virtual machine (VM) instead of natively by the underlying operating system.